# Why do my variables keep going back to 0 and why do my variables look different on the screen then in reality?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So for some reason when I try to access variables from another script the text is showing what I put but when I change things in the editor the accrual values don't change. even if in the code I put playerPoints to 9 when I run it its 0 during a collision. I have all the scripts and objects connected up, and when I try to flip where the variables are, make them in the destroy script, for some reason, it doesn't work. it wont let me use public BallsText bt; it will return an error even though it works fine for the other. I'm sorry if all of these are really basic questions but I've looked as far as I can on the internet and I cant find anything, so any help would be appreciated.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BallsText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Destroy destroy;
   // public int playerPoints = 0;
    //public int enemyPoints = 0;

    //int playerPoints = 0;
    //int enemyPoints = 0;

    public Text playerPointsText;
    public Text enemyPointsText;

    void Update()
    {
        playerPointsText.text = destroy.playerPoints.ToString();
        enemyPointsText.text = destroy.enemyPoints.ToString();
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Destroy : MonoBehaviour
{    
    public int playerPoints = 9;
    public int enemyPoints = 0;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (this.name == "Destroy.cs")
        {
            Debug.Log("i have a doughnut");
        }

        if (col.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            Debug.Log(playerPoints);
            playerPoints++;
            Debug.Log(playerPoints);
            Debug.Log("at least im a dounut");
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
            
        }
        else if (col.gameObject.name == "Enemy Zone")
        {

            enemyPoints++;
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: public members are serialized, that means Unity creates a file and stores the value from the editor. The script value is only valid when you create the member. So you created with 0, saved, Unity serialized and shows 0 in Editor. From there on in, only the value set in the editor will be consider. Same applies to private and protected when they get the SerializedField attribute. So for you to affect that value, you need to do it from editor or make them private so serialization is removed for this member.

Comment: But i need them public because im accessing them between scripts, so how do i make them public without being in the editor?

Comment: you can use public int value {get;set;}

Comment: where would i put that, when im changing the variables during collision? or would i put that for the text script?

Comment: public int EnemyPoints =>enemyPoints; same with other members. Then make them private.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide them from the inspector's view with `HideInInspector` while still being public.

```cs
[HideInInspector] public int playerPoints = 9;
```

You can also use the reset script to return the setting of public numbers to the first state.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like [Everts said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72488956/why-do-my-variables-keep-going-back-to-0-and-why-do-my-variables-look-different#comment128053297_72488956), you had the value at zero and created an instance of the script. Now when you change the script Unity will serialize (save) all the public/serialized fields, then reload the script, then deserialize (load) all the public/serialized fields it previously saved. This means your values are locked into the **instance** that you previously used. If you make a new instance, you get the current values, and if you reset the script you'll get the current values.

This has also bitten me enough times that I don't set default values when variables are declared anymore. If you have a value that you want to use, set those values in `Start()` or `Awake()`.

The advantage here is that whatever is in the script will get overwritten when play mode starts. The disadvantage is that you can't customize those values on a per-instance basis anymore, because *all* instances of the script will all load the same default values when play mode starts. If this matters to you, and you *want* to be able to customize those values, then unfortunately you'll need to go to each script and change those values manually.

If you use a property with an automatic backing field then you won't be able to see it in the editor

```
public class Destroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public int playerPoints{get; set;} = 9; // Can't see this in the editor
    public int enemyPoints{get; set;} = 0; // Can't see this in the editor
```

If you use a property with an explicit backing field then you can expose the backing field to the editor with the `[SerializeField]` tag, but then you've got the same problem you've got now - the editor *will* serialize that field and subsequent changes to the *script* won't affect *instances*:

```
public class Destroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private int playerPoints_ = 9; // Instances will "lock in" values and later changes to the script here won't take effect
    [SerializeField]
    private int enemyPoints_ = 0; // Instances will "lock in" values and later changes to the script here won't take effect
    public int playerPoints
    {
        get=>playerPoints_; 
        set{playerPoints_ = value;}
    }
    public int enemyPoints
    {
        get=>enemyPoints_; 
        set{enemyPoints_ = value;}
    }
```

If you keep the fields public (and thus exposed to the editor) but set the values at runtime in `Awake()` or `Start()` then you can see the values in the editor but the editor values for *all instances* will be overridden when play mode starts:

```
public class Destroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public int playerPoints; // Doesn't matter what the value is here on instantiation becuase you'll override it on Awake()
    public int enemyPoints; // Doesn't matter what the value is here on instantiation becuase you'll override it on Awake()
    
    public void Awake()
    {
        playerPoints = 9; // Will override *every* instance's values with this.
        enemyPoints = 0; // Will override *every* instance's values with this.
    }
```

:EDIT:

I'll add too that repeatedly polling is wasteful. If you use events then you can subscribe and get notifications when there's something to see. Consider instead:

```
public class Destroy : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int playerPoints = 9;
    private int enemyPoints = 0;

    public System.EventHandler<int> OnPlayerPointsChanged;
    public System.EventHandler<int> OnEnemyPointsChanged;

    
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
{
    
    if (this.name == "Destroy.cs")
    {
        Debug.Log("i have a doughnut");
    }

    if (col.gameObject.name == "Player")
    {
        Debug.Log(playerPoints);
        playerPoints++;
        OnPlayerPointsChanged?.Invoke(this, playerPoints);
        Debug.Log(playerPoints);
        Debug.Log("at least im a dounut");
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
        
    }
    else if (col.gameObject.name == "Enemy Zone")
    {

        enemyPoints++;
        OnEnemyPointsChanged?.Invoke(this, enemyPoints);
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

Now `Destroy` has two public events that fire when the public or enemy points change. Anyone subscribing to those events will get notified when the points change, and part of the event notification is the current point value.

Then your other script subscribes to the events and does whatever they need to when they receive that event. Here they'll convert the points `.ToString()` and update the `Text` values:

```
public class BallsText : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Destroy destroy;
    public Text playerPointsText;
    public Text enemyPointsText;

    private void Start()
    {
        destroy.OnPlayerPointsChanged += PlayerPointsChanged;
        destroy.OnEnemyPointsChanged += EnemyPointsChanged;
    }

    public void PlayerPointsChanged(object sender, int points)
    {
        playerPointsText.text = points.ToString;
    }

    public void EnemyPointsChanged(object sender, int points)
    {
        enemyPointsText.text = points.ToString();
    }
}
```

Last note here is that your `Destroy` script increments `enemyPoints` but then also immediately destroys the gameObject, so I don't see the point in incrementing `enemyPoints` unless there's something else accumulating enemy points. With the subscription model that's totally doable - you could have something else subscribing to the `Destroy` script models and they'll get notifications before the script self-destructs.

Comment: So i made the destroy script on an emty gameobject that never gets destroyed or changed, so i dont understand how destroying an object that it isnt linked to resets the points? also thank you for you other explenations, but when you said i should do OnPlayerPointsChanged?.Invoke(this, playerPoints); How do i set that up? is that a unity function or do i have to create it? thanks again

Comment: @ImBadAtMath You're asking how you set that up, but I've given you functional scripts here, so I'm not sure what you're asking. You call `OnPlayerPointsChanged?.Invoke(this, playerPoints)` wherever you want to broadcast that `playerPoints` has changed.

Comment: The problem you might be having is if you really do have this script on an empty gameObject. The `void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)` method will only get called if the gameObject that `Destroy` is attached to has a collider. Right now, `Destroy` is keeping the `playerPoints` and `enemyPoints` and when you call `Destroy(this.gameObject);` it destroys itself - you'll lose all the `playerPoints` and `enemyPoints`. In programming any reference to `this` means the current instance of the object.

Comment: So the destroy script is on both the object that gets destroyed and an emty gameobject as well, as i thought that the gameobject would prevent the script from being deleted. When i ran your code and put some debugs in it i found that now the balls text doesnt work, there is no number only text, and the points are also broken, switching from 9 to 10. If i can figure our a way to make the destroy script not self destruct i think that will solve my problem, aloght im not sure how.

Comment: @ImBadAtMath - you should read up on [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and try to think critically about what you're trying to do. It sounds to me like you're wanting a scorekeeper that tracks collisions, but you're putting the scorekeeping logic on the objects that are part of the game.

Comment: This is like attaching a billboard to a baseball - when the baseball is hit out-of-bounds you lose the score, too! If you put the scoring system on an empty gameObject then you can [tag and find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindWithTag.html) that scoring system in `Awake()` for the balls and add the scoring system to their event handlers. The first argument in an event is always the `object` that is sending the event, so you could remove the ball after a score by deleting the gameObject attached to the sender, like `Object.Destroy(((MonoBehaviour)sender).gameObject)`

Comment: I tryed to switch it around and put the score keeping varables in my text script, however when i went to make a public BallsText bt; it gave an error. how do i host the variables seperatly if i cant use variables from other scripts? do i switch the onplayerpointschanged to the ballstext script? Because it wont let me declare the varaibles in any other script than they very one its destroynig, i cant make any progress.

Comment: @ImBadAtMath usually you have some instantiator or game manager script that populates everything else and that's what would link your things together. You'd have a game manager script that instantiates balls, links the scoreboard, monitors win conditions, resets the stage/players, etc. It's nice to be able to drag and drop in the editor but life is difficult until you leave that stuff behind. Drag and drop key pillars off your game (manager and scoreboard, etc.) and let the manager script instantiate everything else. After you instantiate you hold those references and can use them later.